# Как сделать чтоб вместе с input type="raio" приходил еще один input?

Tags: php, html, jquery

Есть такая форма:

```html
<form action="WinUser.php" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_match" value="4">
  <label>
          <input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="win" value="1" checked>ZZ
          <input type="hidden" name="koof" value="1.2">  
      </label>
  <label>
          <input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="win" value="2">GG
          <input type="hidden" name="koof" value="5.2">
      </label>

  <p class="uk-text-right">
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close" type="button">Отменить</button>
    <button id="button-win" class="uk-button th-button-win" type="submit">Подтвердить</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Как сделать чтоб при выборе `input="radio" name="win" value="1"` шел `input type="hidden" name="koof" value="1.2"`, а при выборе `input type="radio" name="win" value="2"`приходил `input type="hidden" name="koof" value="5.2"`?

Есть идея, сделать из полей `type="hidden"` поля `type="radio"`, и при выборе тех radio выбирались одновременно и эти поля. Только не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно быть только один поля `<input type="hidden" name="koof" value="">` и после выбора изменить значение.

Еще я добавил `data-koof="1.2"` и `data-koof="5.2"`.

```js
$("form#WinUser input[checked]").each(function(e) {
  $("form#WinUser input[name=koof]").val($(this).data('koof'));
});
$("form#WinUser input[type=radio]").change(function(e) {
  if (this.checked) {
    $("form#WinUser input[name=koof]").val($(this).data('koof'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="WinUser.php" method="POST" id="WinUser">
  <input type="hidden" name="id_match" value="4">
  <label>
      <input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="win" value="1" data-koof="1.2" checked>ZZ
  </label>
  <label>
      <input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="win" value="2" data-koof="5.2">GG
  </label>
  <input type="hidden" name="koof" value="">

  <p class="uk-text-right">
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-default uk-modal-close" type="button">Отменить</button>
    <button id="button-win" class="uk-button th-button-win" type="submit">Подтвердить</button>
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Как я понял в скрипте в строчке data('нужное значение') ставится?

Comment: @Евгений нет нечего трогать не надо. Просто можно изменить здесь на другой значение `data-koof="1.2"`

Comment: ааа.... все вижу..

Comment: @Евгений ваш проблема решено или ?

Comment: да, благодарю...

Comment: @Евгений Всегда пожалуйста...

Answer (score 0):

при выборе

```
<input class="uk-radio" type="radio" name="win" value="1" checked>ZZ
```

должен появится

```
<input type="hidden" name="koof" value="5.2">
```

но изначальное состояние  `input name="koof"` скрытое?

я тебя правильно понимаю?

Comment: скрытое, типа display:none? нет, у него просто type="hidden"....